# Undefined error on defined function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a function that multiplies polynomials (represented using lists -- 3x^2 + 5x + 2 = P [2,5,3]):

```
newtype Poly a = P [a]

plus :: Num a => Poly a -> Poly a -> Poly a
plus (P a) (P b) = P (map (\(y,z) -> z + y) (zipWithPadding 0 a b))
    where
        zipWithPadding :: (Num a) => a -> [a] -> [a] -> [(a, a)]
        zipWithPadding e (aa: as) (bb: bs) = ((aa, bb): zipWithPadding e as bs)
        zipWithPadding e [] bs = zip (repeat e) bs
        zipWithPadding e as [] = zip as (repeat e)

times :: Num a => Poly a -> Poly a -> Poly a
times (P a) (P b) = sum $ multList 0 [] a b
    where
        multList :: Num a => Int -> [Poly a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [Poly a]
        multList _ s [] _ = s
        multList e s (aa:as) bs = multList (e + 1) (s ++ (multElement e aa bs)) as bs

        multElement :: Num a => Int -> a -> [a] -> [Poly a]
        multElement e aa bs = [P $ replicate e 0 ++ (map (*aa) bs)]


instance Num a => Num (Poly a) where
    (+) = plus
    (*) = times
    negate      = undefined
    fromInteger = undefined
    -- No meaningful definitions exist
    abs    = undefined
    signum = undefined
```

When I tried to run however, I got an `undefined` error:

```
*HW04> times (P [1,2,2]) (P [1,2])
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

I'm confused.

Comment: This code does not compile, I get the error :

     Could not deduce (Num (Poly a)) arising from a use of `sum'

Comment: now it should, i didn't include the `plus` function

Comment: That doesn't make any difference, `sum` actually needs a `Num` instance.

Comment: Ok, now it definitely does.

Comment: btw - there is a bug in your definition of `plus` - e.g. try `plus (P [1]) (P [2,3])`

Comment: You should have `negate (P cs) = P (map negate cs)` and `fromInteger x = [x]`. These are entirely straightforward for polynomials.

Comment: Your instance is invalid.  Neither `abs`, `fromInteger`, nor `signum` are optional, and while you can omit a definition of `negate` as long as you provide a definition for `(-)`, you can't explicitly leave it undefined.

Comment: @chepner, `abs` and `signum` don't seem sensible in this context. The rest can be fixed easily.

Comment: I'd argue that abusing `Num` like this is no better than doing the same thing so that we could "add" two lists rather than defining the `(++)` operator.

Comment: What would be a good Type for polynomials other than `Num`, I'm doing this because I'm learning Haskell on my own with the CIS 194 course and that is the set up for one of the homeworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polynomial is not really a Num, although there is a ring monomorphism `Num a => a -> Poly a`.

Discard that Num instance and use `foldl plus` instead of `sum`.

Comment: Polynomials form rings, which is more than you can say for floating point representations, and are even commutative under rather weak conditions. The `Num` class has no laws to speak of, so I don't really see a problem with the OP's instance.

Comment: I agree: this instance _is_ sensible, though I'm generally a big critic of giving types a `Num` instance if they aren't really number types. Nevertheless, +1 if only because it's always good to remind yourself how you can get along without type classes. But... surely it should be `foldl'`?

Comment: Num has methods `abs :: a -> a` and `signum :: a -> a`, which are not defined for polynomials.

Comment: Besides, `foldl'` is more efficient here indeed.

Comment: @leftaroundabout what would you have used instead of `Num`, this is the set up from a homework file (I'm teaching myself haskell using the CIS 194 course).

Comment: @Liumx31: for many types, [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) is an excellent abstraction: addition and scaling are perfectly natural, but vector⊕vector→vector multiplication is usually not quite well-defined (it depends on a choice of basis). In the case of polynomials, multiplication is clear and unambiguous though, hence I'd say the `Num` instance is ok. (Though indeed `abs` and `signum` are problematic – you could actually define these by e.g. integration over the unit interval, but that's not natural anymore).

Comment: Use class Data.Algebra.Ring to get an addition and a multiplication.

Comment: @Semeria: to make that concrete: I'd propose the definition `abs f = √( ₀∫¹ d (f )² )` and `signum f = f / √( ₀∫¹ d (f )² )`. That fulfills: **1.** `abs f ≡ realToFrac n` for some `n ≥ 0` (with `n==0` iff `f==0`) **2.** `abs (signum f) ≡ 1` for all `f ≠ 0` **3.** `abs f * signum f == f`. So IMO that would be a fine `Num` instance, quite useful and efficient to compute, though it's not completely natural.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly you are calling one of the `undefined` methods in the Num instance for Poly.

You can determine which one is being called by using these definitions:

```
negate      = error "Poly negate undefined"
fromInteger = error "Poly fromInteger undefined"
abs    = error "Poly abs undefined"
signum = error "Poly signum undefined"
```

Running your test expression yields:

```
Poly *** Exception: Poly fromInteger undefined
```

The problem is in your use of `sum` which is essentially defined as:

```
sum xs = foldl (+) 0 xs
```

It is therefore calling `fromInteger 0`. You can fix this with:

```
fromInteger x = P [ fromInteger x ]
```

**Update**

The reason `fromInteger` for `Poly a` needs to be defined this way is
because we need to construct a list of `Num a` values, and `fromInteger x`
is the way to create a `Num a` from the Integer value `x`.

Comment: I think it should be `fromInteger x = P [fromInteger x]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take the position that you should not define an instance of a class simply to hijack the class's functions. The minimal definition of a `Num` instance expects certain functions to be defined; explicitly assigning `undefined` to those names does not qualify as a definition. Consider that Haskell provides a specific operator `(++)` for list concatenation instead of simply overloading `(+)` with an instance like

```
instance Num [a] where
    a + [] = a
    [] + b = b
    (a:as) + b = a:(as + b)
    (*) = undefined
    negate = undefined
    -- etc
```

---

Instead, define a class that *does* provide the operations you want. In this case, you want a `Ring`, which is a type along with two operations, addition and multipication, that obey certain laws. (Put briefly, the operations act as you would expect given the integers as an example, except multiplication is not required to be commutative.)

In Haskell, we would define the class as

```
class Ring a where
    rplus :: a -> a -> a -- addition
    rmult :: a -> a -> a -- multiplication
    rnegate :: a -> a    -- negation
    runit :: a           -- multiplicative identity
    rzero :: a           -- additive identity, multiplicative zero
```

Any value with a valid `Num` instance forms a ring, although you need to define the instances separately.

```
instance Ring Integer where
    rplus = (+)
    rmult = (*)
    rnegate = negate
    rzero = 0
    runit = 1

instance Ring Float
    rplus = (+)
    rmult = (*)
    rnegate = negate
    rzero = 0
    runit = 1

-- etc
```

You can define an instance of `Ring` for polynomials, as long as the coefficients form a ring as well.

```
newtype Poly a = P [a]

instance Ring a => Ring (Poly a) where
    -- Take care to handle polynomials with different degree
    -- Note the use of rplus and rzero instead of (+) and 0
    -- when dealing with coefficients
    rplus (P a) (P b) = case (compare (length a) (length b)) of
                          LT -> rplus (P (rzero:a)) (P b)
                          EQ -> P $ zipWith rplus a b
                          GT -> rplus (P a) (P (rzero:b))



    -- I leave a correct implementation of rmult as an exercise
    -- for the reader.
    rmult = ...
    rnegate (P coeffs) = P $ map rnegate coeffs
    rzero = P [0]
    runit = P [1]
```